# How can I show notifications for longer than the default timeout?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I would like to show a HTML5 notification to a user for longer than the default time. I've set a timeout for 30 seconds but the browser is clearing the notification before the full time is being run. How can I extend the time for a notification?

```
function testNotification() {
  var callNotification = new Notification('Notification Title', {
    body: "Notification Body"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    callNotification.close();
  }, 30000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `requireInteraction` to the notification options, as the name implies, requires interaction from the user to close the notification. Should the user not close the notification manually, it will be closed after the timeout expires.

```
function testNotification() {
  var callNotification = new Notification('Notification Title', {
    body: "Notification Body",
    requireInteraction: true
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    callNotification.close();
  }, 30000);
}
```